# Mathematical operations on columns specified by vector in R

Tags: r, replace, subset

I need to replace specific values in a subset of columns in my dataframe. Specifically, I need to replace the value 1 in this subset of columns with 0.9999. I created a vector containing the column names of columns where replacement is needed. These columns must be subset by name and not column number.

```
peaches <- c( 0, 1, 0, 1)
bananas <- c( 0, 1, 1, 1)
apples <- c( 1, 1, 1, 1)
oranges <- c (0, 0, 0, 1)
fruits <- data.frame(peaches, bananas, apples, oranges)
vector <- c("apples", "bananas", "peaches")
```

My first attempt looked like this:

```
fruits[vector][fruits[vector] == 1] <- 0.9999
```

While it works for this small dataset, it is not transforming values in the large dataset I'm working with. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tidyverse solution

```r
library(tidyverse)

peaches <- c( 0, 1, 0, 1)
bananas <- c( 0, 1, 1, 1)
apples <- c( 1, 1, 1, 1)
oranges <- c (0, 0, 0, 1)
fruits <- data.frame(peaches, bananas, apples, oranges)
vector <- c("apples", "bananas", "peaches")

fruits %>% 
  mutate_at(vector, ~ replace(., . == 1, .9999))
#>   peaches bananas apples oranges
#> 1  0.0000  0.0000 0.9999       0
#> 2  0.9999  0.9999 0.9999       0
#> 3  0.0000  0.9999 0.9999       0
#> 4  0.9999  0.9999 0.9999       1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Beat me to it by like 3 seconds. But I would do something like this instead: `mutate_at(vector, ~ replace(., . == 1, .9999))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`fruits[,vector][fruits[,vector] == 1] <- 0.9999`

`fruits[vector]` uses the fact that a data.frame is a list of vector (of the same length), maybe the "matrix" approach is more adapted.

Comment: I get this error code: Error in `[.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , LGSTC) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'LGSTC' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..LGSTC]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 Is your object a data.table?

Comment: Not sure... how would I check if it's a dataframe or datatable?

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 You can look it up with ``str(data)`` or ``is.data.table(data)`` but if you are using the ``data.table`` package with your data, you have probably ''convert'' your data.frame to a data.table, while they are alike, some errors can occur. The error you posted mentions data.table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
fruits[,vector] <- setDT(lapply(fruits[,vector], function(x) replace(x, x==1, 0.9999)))

  peaches bananas apples oranges
1  0.0000  0.0000 0.9999  0.0000
2  0.9999  0.9999 0.9999  0.0000
3  0.0000  0.9999 0.9999  0.0000
4  0.9999  0.9999 0.9999  0.9999
```

Comment: Dont forget the [vector] specification ;-) You can also try : `fruits[,vector] <- apply(fruits[,vector], 2, function(x) { replace(x, x==1, 0.9999) })`

Comment: And thanks for the `setDT()` function I didn't know !

Comment: Yes you'll find that ``setDT()`` can come handy while working on large dataset!

Comment: Ça permet d'éviter de faire des copies inutiles, c'est donc beaucoup plus efficient et rapide comme méthode sur de grosses bases de données!